# Query showing ID instead of description

Tags: sql, ms-access, ms-access-2007

It works fine untill I start using UNION ALL!
Have to use classified here because I'm not allowed to share too much information

It should show the Reden Uitstroom and NOT the ID. I have really no clue why this happens...

**Look-up Table=**

```
ID  Description
1   classified 
2   classified
3   classified
4   classified
5   classified
6   classified
7   classified
8   classified
9   classified
```

**Code =**

```
SELECT        Count(Hertoetsing.[Reden uitstroom1]) AS [Aantal Uitstroom 2014],
                   (Hertoetsing.[Reden uitstroom1]) AS [Reden Uitstroom]

FROM          Klantinformatie     

INNER JOIN    Hertoetsing 
    ON        Klantinformatie.KlantID=Hertoetsing.Klantid

WHERE         (((Year(Hertoetsing.[Datum uitstroom1]))=2014))

GROUP BY      Hertoetsing.[Reden uitstroom1]

UNION ALL

SELECT        Count(Hertoetsing.[Reden uitstroom2]) AS [Aantal Uitstroom 2014],
                   (Hertoetsing.[Reden uitstroom2]) AS [Reden Uitstroom]

FROM          Klantinformatie 

INNER JOIN    Hertoetsing 
    ON        Klantinformatie.KlantID=Hertoetsing.Klantid

WHERE         (((Year(Hertoetsing.[Datum uitstroom2]))=2014))

GROUP BY      Hertoetsing.[Reden uitstroom2]

UNION ALL 

SELECT        Count(Hertoetsing.[Reden uitstroom3]) AS [Aantal Uitstroom 2014],
                   (Hertoetsing.[Reden uitstroom3]) AS [Reden Uitstroom]

FROM          Klantinformatie 

INNER JOIN    Hertoetsing 
    ON        Klantinformatie.KlantID=Hertoetsing.Klantid

WHERE         (((Year(Hertoetsing.[Datum uitstroom3]))=2014))

GROUP BY      Hertoetsing.[Reden uitstroom3];
```

**Result =**

```
Aantal Uitstroom 2014   Reden Uitstroom    
27  1   
25  2   
46  3   
1   4      
3   5   
9   6  
17  8   
3   9      
4   1   
2   2  
5   3   
1   4   
1   6   
1   1   
1   2     
1   3   
2   8
```

**Correcting Group By** =

```
SELECT Sum([Aantal Uitstroom 2014]) AS [Uitstroom 2014], 
                  [Reden Uitstroom] AS [Uitstroom]

FROM [Reden Uitstroom1 2014]

GROUP BY [Reden Uitstroom];
```

**Result =**

```
Uitstroom 2014  Uitstroom
32  1
28  2
52  3
2   4
3   5
10  6
19  8
3   9
```

**EDIT - Another Issues with another query =**

Query runs properly but once I put it into a report then it starts showing the ID from the look-up table instead of description.... This is so weird....

Comment: You write `My Table` but actually, you have several tables. can you clarify ?

Comment: I ment the look-up table sorry. My Acces is in Dutch which I really need to change. It's the look-up table for the drop down list ( reden uitstroom ) in my main table ( Hertoetsing )

Comment: This is a common problem when lookupfields are used in tables. The practice is generally frowned upon, partly because of this. You need to include the lookup table in the query and reference the description field in the lookup table. If this is unclear, please post the actual table structure and relationships, including the lookup table.

Comment: Ok it worked! Just one more issue... It's under EDIT at the bottom.